# Visual Studio .LESS formatting ruined

Tags: visual-studio, less

I'm working on a .less file in Visual Studio and it has been compiling fine (using dotless.complete.exe in project pre-build events).

So far the project has compiled and generated the output .css file fine, however now I'm getting compile errors:

```
1>  Expected '}' but found 'e' on line 2449 in file 'styles.custom.less':
1>  [2448]:                         border-bottom: 1px solid #213840;
1>  [2449]:                         media only screen and (max-width : 768px);
1>         ------------------------^
```

**See my answer for the reason.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I used the Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D (Edit > Format Document) short-cut on the .less file without thinking.
This ruins the formatting on the following section of code:

```
border-bottom:1px solid #213840;

media only screen
and (max-width : 768px) {
    font-size:14px;
}
media only screen
and (max-width : 480px) {
    font-size:11px;
}
```

I suggest you don't use Visual Studio document formatting on .less files.

Comment: If you are using VS2013, download update 2 as it has much better formatting for mediaqueries in Less files.